# Automating Combo Box (drop down + checkbox) using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, drop-down-menu

I am trying to automate the drop down in the website Naukri.com. That drop down consists of multi select check-boxes. How can we automate it using Selenium Web driver?

The structure of the drop list is:

```
<div class="DDwrap">
<ul class="DDsearch">
    <li class="tagit" data-id="tg_indCja_a8_A">
         <span class="tagTxt">Accounting , Finance</span>
         <span class="dCross"></span>
    </li>
   <li class="frst" style="float: left;">
   <input id="cjaInd" class="srchTxt" type="text" placeholder="" name="" autocomplete="off"   style="width: 30px;">    
   <input id="hid_indCja" type="hidden" name="indType" value="["8"]">
   </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me regarding this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check out the code below, It navigates to the concerned form, opens the dropdown of "Industry" and selects two checkboxes: 'Accounting , Finance' and 'Government , Defence':**

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); //Opening firefox instance

driver.manage().window().maximize(); //maximizing window
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //Giving implicit timeout of 20 seconds

driver.get("http://www.naukri.com/");


//Since there are two windows popping up, hence switching and closing the unnecessary window.
Set<String> windows = driver.getWindowHandles();        
Iterator iter = windows.iterator();
String parentWindow = iter.next().toString();
String childWindow = iter.next().toString();        
driver.switchTo().window(childWindow);
driver.close();
driver.switchTo().window(parentWindow);

//Hovering over "Jobs"
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
WebElement jobs = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='midSec menu']//div[.='Jobs']"));
act.moveToElement(jobs).build().perform();

//Clicking on "Advance Search"
WebElement Adv_search = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='midSec menu']/li[1]//a[.='Advanced Search']"));
act.moveToElement(Adv_search).click().perform();

//Clicking on the industry dropdown
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='DDinputWrap']/input[contains(@placeholder,'Select the industry')]")).click();

//Selecting the checkbox containing text as "Accounting"
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='ChkboxEnb']//a[contains(text(),'Accounting')]")).click();

//Selecting the checkbox containing text as 'Government' 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='ChkboxEnb']//a[contains(text(),'Government')]")).click();
```

Comment: @Riki: If it has worked for you, please mark it as answer too. Thanks.. :)

Comment: I think i will catch you up later too..since i'm new to automation ;)

Comment: Hi Shubh, Can you also help in automating the CREATE JOB ALERT page as there are some dynamic class names used there. It worked for me if i am removing //div[@class='DDWrap' from Industry and starting xpath from //input. But that is not unique Can you help please?

Comment: It's better if you ask a new question. It will help others, help you too. Elongating the conversation on question aside from what was originally posted, is not good.. Thanks.. :)